# render map in template using play framework 1.2.3

Tags: playframework

I've got a map where the key is a string but the value is a user defined type/object with multiple fields.  I am using play framework 1.2.3 (using groovy template).  Can anyone share the exact syntax for iterating through the map values (where I can fetch the fields in the object which serves as the value in the map).

This works for a string value - I need the syntax for an object field:

```
#{list amount, as:'Amt'} 
${Amt.value} 
#{/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the values of your map and iterate through them as a normal List or iterate through the keys and get the corresponding map values.

```
#{list mymap.value(), as:'myval'} 
 ${myval.property} 
#{/}
    or
#{list items:mymap.keySet(), as:'key'}
   ${mymap.get(key)}        
#{/list}
```

Comment: thanks emt - I was clearly not thinking properly when I posted the question.

Comment: I'm not success with this solution. Currently, I'm using play 1.3.2 :-/ Any suggestion, please?